# Evince error: "failed to map segment from shared object"

Tags: command-line, 18.04, evince

Evince does not open the pdf from a terminal instead, it gives the error:

```
EvinceDocument-Warning: liblcms2.so.2: failed to map segment from shared object
```

Opening the file using Firefox or Foxit reader works. 
I tried to search the error but couldn't find any valid solution.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall evince? `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt purge evince && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt install evince`

Comment: Please check the following - do you have multiple libraries with `sudo find / -name liblcms2.so.2` and evince dynamic linkings by `ldd $(which evince) | grep liblcms2`. Add the outputs to the question by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1209686/edit) it.

Comment: @Gryu I have tried reinstalling evince but it still didn't work.

Comment: @N0rbert I don't have a root account to execute `sudo find / liblcms2`. But the output of `ldd $(which evince)...` is empty!! which is weird.

Comment: @Malik How then have you been reinstalling `evince` without root account? ))

Comment: @Gryu I have some root access but not full. I can install packages.